# Ошибка в простой задаче: пишет ожидался оператор, а встретил else

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

Pascal. Ошибка в простой задаче: пишет ожидался оператор, а встретил else.

```
program MaxIn_3;

var
    x, y, z, res: real;

begin
    writeln('Введите целые числа: X, Y, Z');
    readln(x, y, z);
    res := x + y + z;
    if (res < 1) then
    begin
        if (x > y) and (x <> y) then
        begin
            y := (y + z) / 2;
            writeln('X=', x, ',', 'Y=', y, ',', 'Z=', z, '.');
        end
            else
            begin
            if (y > x) and (x <> y) then
                 begin
                    x := (y + z) / 2;
                    writeln('X=', x, ',', 'Y=', y, ',', 'Z=', z, '.');
                 end
                 else
                 begin
                 Writeln('X=Y,',x,'=',y);
                 end;
            **end;// - если убрать здесь ; то пишет MaxIn_3.pas(29) : Встречено 'else', а ожидалось ';'**

         **else** //вот здеся ошибка, видимо мне мозгов не хватает понять

            begin
            if (x>y) and (x <> y) then
             begin
             x:=x*y;
             writeln('X=', x, ',', 'Y=', y, ',', 'Z=', z, '.');
             end
                else
                 begin
                 if (y>x) and (x <> y) then
                        begin
                        y:=x*y;
                        writeln('X=', x, ',', 'Y=', y, ',', 'Z=', z, '.');
                        end
                            else
                            begin
                            Writeln('X=Y,',x,'=',y);
                            end;
                 end;
            end;
    end;

end.
```

Среда программирования **PascalABC.NET**, *по моей блок-схеме все верно, разделы операторов вроде все на месте,* **в чем может быть ошибка? Или у меня косоглазие просто?**

Comment: Сама задача(чтоб вы поняли смысл сия "творения")
Если сумма различных трех чисел X,Y,Z, меньше единицы, то меньшее из X, Y заменить полусуммой Y и Z, иначе большее из X, Y заменить произведением X*Y.

Comment: не вдаваясь в то, что ваш код делает: между `end` и `else` надо убрать точку с запятой.

Comment: В паскале перед `else`  не может стоять точка с запятой.

Comment: я тоже так думал... и когда убрал, то написало - MaxIn_3.pas(29) : Встречено 'else', а ожидалось ';'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Перед ЭТИМ else, еще 1 end должен быть...

```
program MaxIn_3;
var
  x, y, z, res: real;
begin
  writeln('Введите целые числа: X, Y, Z');
  readln(x, y, z);
  res := x + y + z;
  if (res < 1) then
    begin
      if (x > y) and (x <> y) then
        begin
          y := (y + z) / 2;
          writeln('X=', x, ',', 'Y=', y, ',', 'Z=', z, '.');
        end
      else
        begin
          if (y > x) and (x <> y) then
            begin
              x := (y + z) / 2;
              writeln('X=', x, ',', 'Y=', y, ',', 'Z=', z, '.');
            end
          else
            begin
              Writeln('X=Y,',x,'=',y);
            end
        end
    end
  else
    begin
      if (x>y) and (x <> y) then
        begin
          x:=x*y;
          writeln('X=', x, ',', 'Y=', y, ',', 'Z=', z, '.');
        end
      else
        begin
          if (y>x) and (x <> y) then
            begin
              y:=x*y;
              writeln('X=', x, ',', 'Y=', y, ',', 'Z=', z, '.');
            end
          else
            begin
              Writeln('X=Y,',x,'=',y);
            end
        end
    end

end.
```

> http://pascalabc.net/WDE/?file=04013.pas

Comment: Наглядный пример, когда форматирование кода просто необходимо! )